# How to improve Facebook Event Matching ( Click ID - fbc ) Shopify

Tags: html, facebook, web

I've set up my Facebook conversion API in my shopify store. However my Click ID (fbc) score is low.. how can i improve this? i've tried to search in the internet and i'm not sure how i can improve this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that give you low percent (31%). But first documentation

> When a user clicks on an ad on Facebook, the link sometimes includes a fbclid query parameter. When the user lands on the target website, if the website has a Facebook pixel that uses first-party cookies, the pixel automatically saves the fbclid query parameter to an _fbc cookie for that website domain.
> [Documentation-Fbc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/fbp-and-fbc/#fbc)

When user open your site without clicking ad links but simply googling or typing URL, then pixel sets only fbp cookie. Your data is mixed every user with fbc and without, that's why you get 31%

If user use adBlock then pixel can't create any of cookies.

If you want to increase score 4.7 then you could add more info about who is logged, but still there be a percent of people being anonymous (reducing your score and percent).

Comment: Thank you for the response! However, assuming most of my audiences are mobile users.. how can I improve this? considering if they're not using adBlock in their mobile? It seems that I need to manually insert the custom parameter into my event but I do not see any clear instruction for this. My conversion API is set up automatically and they did not include the fbc event parameters..

Comment: @TeikCheah "My conversion API is set up automatically" - what you're using?

Comment: @TeikCheah If access to your page is restricted to users with fbclid (in url) then score would be 100% - % of users using adBlock.  Right now it's a sum of users entering the site from ad and simply typing URL or googling. And only 31% are from your ads, and there could be a % with adBlock if it was from desktop (duno if mobile have adBlock)

Comment: Hello Patrick!

My conversion API is also set up automatically. However its missing the fbc & fbp.. so im trying to set this parameter up into my standard event.. any idea?